# Rails compressing data before saving to database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, compression

I need to store large amount of data into the database (MySQL). I would like to save disk space by compressing the text data before storing it to the database.

I know there will be a performance hit for compressing/decompressing data. But I am going to cache the decompressed data on CDN. And mostly, the data will not become stale for months or even years.

Can you please refer me some good compression/decompression techniques? I am also open to other alternatives than compressing/decompressing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a pure MySQL solution, you could always try using the `ARCHIVE` storage type for your table. [The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/archive-storage-engine.html) describes it as an insert-only, no update type of engine meant specifically for what you describe, stashing away things that won't change for years.

To do the same thing in a conventional engine would require using `zlib` on your data streams, but remember that compression performs very poorly on already compressed data such as most popular image types or video. You express your requirements as mostly text, which usually compresses quite well.

Ruby has `Zlib::Deflate` which can compress and expand data on demand. You could write your own wrapper similar to the [JSON one](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/) by implementing the `encode` and `decode` methods on your module.

One thing to consider is you can probably store the compressed data on your CDN so long as you can be sure your client supports `gzip` encoding. I don't know of any major browsers that don't, as asset compression has become quite standard, especially in the mobile space.

Comment: The ZLib option is really neat way of compressing and decompressing but if the data is really as static (May not even changing for years) then surely db storage is not the best idea? Mongo or other file storage solutions or XML would be better options wouldn't they?

Comment: If you're storing a lot of large things, then the filesystem approach might be superior as the marginal overhead due to minimum block-size won't be serious. You can always store everything in `.tar.gz` or `.gz` by default, too. A SQLite index and a filesystem store would be the most portable and scalable by far.

Comment: Maintaining a database, especially an irregular one made with hand-rolled XML or an uncommon engine like MongoDB might make maintenance difficult. Mongo is a great platform, but it is evolving rapidly and needs to be updated frequently to stay current. SQLite, while not as full featured, can be depended on even years from now.

Answer (score -2):

If the data is really as static as you say then save the data as zipped xml files.

You can unzip them and zip them up again really easily as and when needed and in Rails generating an XML file is dead simple using SomeModel.to_xml the output of which can easily be sent to a file so maintaining them will be a simple too. You can just as eaily work this the other way round so that when it comes to reading the data in you can simply convert the data back into a model (Rails 3.x has ActiveModel which would be ideal for this scenario as the data is not backed by a database but you still get a ActiveRecord API and all the juice that AR gives you meaning that your views, controllers etc are working with a consistent api and consistent behaviour.

You have other options as well such as using ActiveResource but I wouldn't think that was necessary.
Not a recommended approach if you were not to be caching the data in the way you suggest (which is a neat solution BTW)

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a perfectly valid answer why has it been voted down? surely not because it's a little different? I have clearly stated that it's only recommended if the data is really static and Rails can easily handle XML plus it's being cached so what's the issue?

Comment: XML and Zip files sounds like a whole ton of work for what should be a simple problem of serialization.

Comment: Not that interesting really, Just bog standard Rails stuff. All RESTfull routes will handle XML automatically and it's easy (using ActiveResource or ActiveRecord to get the xml data back into a state fo usage within the app in the normal way.

Comment: If you want to know how to do it then that's a different question entirely really. Just good enough to know it can be done to answer this question as there is no point explaining something unless the explanation is needed and any Rails developer should know how simple this is to do anyway.

Comment: Converting a model to XML isn't the issue here, necessarily. You could use JSON or YAML just the same. The issue is compression, which XML is certainly not a form of.

Comment: Totally agree @tadman, The zlib library is definitely the best compression solution from a simplicity point of view as per accepted answer